# Combinatorial interpretation of $q$-analogue of the binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics

We have the $q$-analogue of the binomial theorem: $(1+t)(1+qt)\cdots (1+q^{n-1}t)=\sum_{k=0}^n q^{k\choose 2} \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  n\\
  k
\end{array}
\right]_q t^k$. What is a combinatorial interpretation for this?

So far I've seen that $\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  k+l\\
  k
\end{array}
\right]_q=\sum_{\lambda\in P}q^{|\lambda|}$ where $P$ is the set of all partitions $\lambda$ which lie inside the $k\times l$ rectangle and $|\lambda|$ is the sum of all parts of $\lambda$.

I do not see the correlation between this combinatorial interpretation of $\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  k+l\\
  k
\end{array}
\right]_q$ and the $q$-analogue of the binomial theorem. I'm also confused by what the terms $(1+t)(1+qt)\cdots (1+q^{n-1}t)$ mean.

It would be appreciated if someone could provide explanations.